# Explain example code (c programming)

Tags: c

The code below is from a c programming tutorial book. The purpose is to find the average of 10 floating-point value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void avg(double *d, int num);

int main(void)
{
    double nums[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,
                   6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0}

    avg(nums,10);

    return 0;
}

void avg(double *d, int num)
{
    double sum;
    int temp;

    temp=num-1;

    for(sum=0;temp>=0;temp--)
        sum=sum+d[temp];
    printf("Average is %f", sum/(double)num);
}
```

What happens when d[temp] is used in line 23.

Comment: Bad style to use `sum = 0` as the initialization (when there is already `temp = num - 1` above). What book is this ?

Comment: Also use of "temp" as iterator when one expects `i`, also iterating down.. this is just bad code all around.

Comment: More bad style; have `avg` write the value to standard output instead of returning it to `main`.  Kind of defeats the purpose of creating the function in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum=sum+d[temp]
```

Where you are accessing every `temp`th element of double array `d`.

If you are having 3 numbers

```
temp=num-1; // temp =2

for(sum=0;temp>=0;temp--)
    sum=sum+d[temp];
```

will expand to-

```
sum=0+d[2]; then temp becomes 1 // you are adding 2nd element with sum
sum=sum+d[1]; then temp becomes 0 // here you are adding with previous result // First element + sum
sum=sum+d[0]; then temp becomes -1 // condition fails // 0th element + sum
```

It is simply-

```
sum=d[2]+d[1]+d[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`d[temp]` means to access the `temp`th element of the array pointed to by `d`.  I.e. `d` points to an array of **at least** `temp+1` `double`s, and you wish to retrieve the `temp`th of those.

Comment: That's the important and often confusing thing. Arrays of X and pointers to X are interchangeable. +1

Comment: @0xC0000022L not *always* interchangeable, but *often* interchangeable (due to pointer decay)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: fair enough. Point being that most beginners don't get that duality at all.

Answer (score 0):

In line 23

`d[temp]` will get the float data of the index with 
 `temp` in `nums` 
 array,

In another term `d[temp]` will replace with the `temp + 1` th element of `nums` array.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over your nums[]-Array and on this line, you add all values to your some variable. 
d[temp] access the value of the item on index temp.